# Why do I keep a Transactional Context out of the EJB?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I have two layers in a POC with WildFly 10.
A Webservice with JaxRS calls an EJB maintaining a `@PersistenceContext`.

It handles for fun a wallet of lines of cryptoCurrencies.

Each line know its Wallet with a `@ManyToOne` to be fast with the database, but the Business logic says that a Wallet should know its Lines.

So I have a circular dependency: The Wallet knows its Line, each line know its Wallet.

```
@Stateless
public class WalletBusiness {

    // EntityManager is given by Wildfly. It's a managed object
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public JpaWallet findWallet(int id) {
        // transaction is opened in your back
        JpaWallet w = em.find(JpaWallet.class, id);

        String jpql = "SELECT l FROM JpaLine l JOIN l.wallet w WHERE w.id = :id";

        List<JpaLine> lines = em.createQuery(jpql, JpaLine.class)
                .setParameter("id", id)
                .getResultList();

        w.setLines(lines);

        return w;
    }// and now closed. <=== Argh: is it ???
}
```

The JaxRS Webservice fetch the Wallet and then cuts the circular dependency.

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
public Wallet getWallet(@PathParam("id") int walletId){

    JpaWallet wallet = walletBusiness.findWallet(walletId);
    // I thought that now, I'm out of the transactionnal context

    // Creating a kind of DTO: Data Transfer Object
    // Cutting circular reference
    wallet.getLines().stream()
        .forEach(jpaLine -> jpaLine.setWallet(null));

    return wallet;

}
```

It's displayed on the web as expected, but when cutting dependency, I delete Lines on the database ! The client is ruined when I thought the persistence context was  closed when getting out of the EJB method.

Where do I miss something ?

Here are the two Entities:

```
@Entity
public class JpaWallet implements Wallet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    int id;

    String name;

    @Transient // Don't want to save in database. It is a Business attribute, not a database item
    List<JpaLine> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }



    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public List<JpaLine> getLines() {
        return lines;
    }

    public void setLines(List<JpaLine> lines) {
        this.lines = lines;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}


@Entity
public class JpaLine implements Line{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    int id;

    String symbol;

    double quantity;

    @ManyToOne
    JpaWallet wallet;


    @Override
    @XmlAttribute(name = "coin")
    public String getSymbol() {
        return this.symbol;
    }

    @Override
    public double getQuantity() {
        return this.quantity;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public void setQuantity(double quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public JpaWallet getWallet() {
        return wallet;
    }

    public void setWallet(JpaWallet wallet) {
        this.wallet = wallet;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.symbol+ ": "+this.quantity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a new feature of Java EE 7:

> JTA provides transaction support to EJB and now in Java EE 7 to CDI managed
>   beans annotated with @Transactional

The Webservice layer uses CDI and the Transactional context is extended in the Webservice. I don't like that : JSF could generate plenty of sql queries.

My solution is to add an annotation in the webservice :

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
// CDI is now able to continue the transaction opened by walletBusiness
// Shut it down there
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.NEVER)
public Wallet getWallet(@PathParam("id") int walletId){

    JpaWallet wallet = walletBusiness.findWallet(walletId);

    // No more propagation. 
    wallet.getLines().stream().forEach(jpaLine -> jpaLine.setWallet(null));

    return wallet;
}
```

Comment: Actually I think it has nothing to do with CDI /@Transactional as it's not appearing in the code ... I think the issue is that you are using @Stateless bean which is usually associated with extended persistence context which continues (entity remains managed)  till the clinent removes it ... But the weird thing is that it needs to be explicitly declared @PersistenceContext(persistence context type.EXTENDED) other wise it will be defaulted to TRANSACTION .... did u declare it in the code like that?

Comment: No, I didn't declare anything. The persistence.xml is minimalist.

Comment: Can u plz show the class in which get wallet is defined? ... Did u annotate it with @Transactional?